# complex associations with active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

For the sake of simplicity I've written this question as if writing a blog application but in actual fact it's an entirely different application. I have a show action similar to this in my users_controller.rb.

```
   def show 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @posts = @user.posts   
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end 
   end
```

Each `post` also has many `comments`. If I wanted to show all of the user posts and comments on those posts (**regardless of which user made the comment**), in the `views/user/show.html.erb`, it's fairly easy to access those comments from the obvious association between posts and comments.

```
<% for post in @posts %>

<% post.comments.each do |c| %>

...
```

That will give me all the comments on those posts, not just the comments the user made, which is what I want.

Now, I'm using active model serializer in this application, and in the User serializer, I can declare the association with posts `has_many :posts`, and then if I go to localhost:3000/user/1.json, I see the user details and the posts.  However, I can't declare `has_many :comments` unless I only want the comments that that user made. However, I want all the comments on those posts regardless of the user who made them.

How could I achieve this with active model serializer?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new serializer for Posts that includes all comments:

```
class FullPostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  has_many :comments

  def comments
    object.comments
  end

end
```

Then use the FullPostSerializer in your User serializer:

`has_many :post, serializer: FullPostSerializer`